# for the same video, why can not play it in safari and chrome on mobile?

Tags: google-chrome, video, safari

I an unable to get the a video to play on my iPhone 7.

I thought it might have just been a Safari issue but it’s also happening on Chrome on my iPhone which I think is still web-kit.

the video link as following: http://misc.saohuijia.com/bdtmobile/video/ugo.mp4

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

1. be sure the video linked is valid: e.g. try other mp4 files: http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/test.html
2. install 3rd-party players, e.g. "VLC for iOS"